# Replace pattern in string with the order from another vector in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

Suppose I have a string x <- "abc%de%fgh%ijk%" and I have a vector y <- c(1,2,3,4).  Is there a clean way in base R to replace the % in x with the ordered vector y with the result being x <- "abc1de2fgh3ijk4"?

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can split the 'x' at `%` and then `paste` with 'y'

```
paste0(strsplit(x, "%", fixed = TRUE)[[1]], y, collapse = "")
```

-output

```
[1] "abc1de2fgh3ijk4"
```

---

We may also use `gsubfn` to insert the count at `%`

```
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) count )
gsubfn("%", p, x)
```

If the 'y' values are different, use the `count` as index to extract the 'y'

```
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) y[count])
gsubfn("%", p, x)
```

i.e. for different values of 'y'

```
> y <- c(24, 31, 15, 23)
> gsubfn("%", p, x)
[1] "abc24de31fgh15ijk23"
```

#### data

```
x <- "abc%de%fgh%ijk%"
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply.  I was hoping to learn in Base R.

Comment: @PeterBonate updated with `base R`